# Funcion para buscar en una cadena las comas y remplazarlas por punto

Tags: javascript

quiero hacer una función que al pasarle por ejemplo esta cantidad 20000,01 me retorne 20000.01

```js
function cambiarDecimales(monto)
{
 var montoEnv;
 montoEnv =  new Intl.NumberFormat(["en-US"],{maximumFractionDigits:2}).format(monto);

 if(contry == 'v' || contry == 'c') {
  montoEnv = montoEnv.replace(/\./g, 'p')
  montoEnv = montoEnv.replace(/\,/g, '.');
  montoEnv = montoEnv.replace(/\p/g, ',');
 }

 return montoEnv;
}
```

Comment: has tratado con la libreria globalizejs? https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#currency-module revisa la parte de el pais para que tome . como miles o , como decimal

Answer (score 1):

No es tan difícil, aunque como comentan arriba existen librearías que hacen el trabajo, pero igual te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo. Tal vez debas realizar un ejemplo que sea mas desarrollado para que no hayan cosas incompletas para la próxima vez.. pero pasando de ello:

Si lo que quieres es una función que puedas usar cada vez que necesites cambiar un monto, tienes que pasar los argumentos necesarios, tales como el monto en cadena de texto, el país (yo obtengo este de un dropdown) y en el ejemplo hago que cambie el valor de una párrafo html por lo que paso un parámetro para identificar la id de este en la función.

Como puedes ver adentro solo tengo que condicionar que si el país es x, en el valor de la cadena se reemplazaran los caracteres especificados en el Regex utilizando el metodo `replace()`, luego solo tengo que brindarle a la función los argumentos que requiere al ejecutar con x metodo.

En el siguiente ejemplo como mencioné arriba, estoy cambiando el valor de mi html dentro de la función en si, pero para obtener el valor de en este caso `cadena` solo la retornamos en la función y haciendo `console.log()` de esta podemos ver que nos da el resultado deseado en forma de cadena.

> Ejemplo:

```js
function evalCountry(cadena, pais, id) {
  var result;
  if (pais == "c"){
    cadena = cadena.replace(/\,/g,".");
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = cadena;
    result = cadena;
  }else if(pais == "p" ){
    cadena = cadena.replace(/\./g,",");
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = cadena;
    result = cadena;
  }
  return result;

}
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var e = document.getElementById("h");
  var country = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var montoEnv = "27644154,00"
  var target = "p";
  console.log(evalCountry(montoEnv, country, target));
});
```

```html
<p id="p">27644154,00</p>
<select id="h" name="country">
  <option value="p">Coma</option>
  <option value="c">Punto</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">convertir</button>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.